# Templates in different directory

Tags: python, django

I want to place the project hierarchy in this way

```
project
 |-app
 |   \app1
 |      |-templates
 |          \app1_templ.html
 |      |- views.py
 |      \-models.py
 |-templates
 |    \main.html
 |-views.py
 |-models.py
 ...
```

But in the main.html i want to use `{%include app1_templ.html%}. Assuming the views.py from the  app1:

```
def main(request):
  info= Informations.objects.all() 
  return render_to_response('main.html', {'a':info})
```

and the app1_templ.html

```
   {% for b in a %}
       <li> title:{{ b.title }}</li>
    {%empty %}
       EMPTY
    {% endfor %}
```

I have put in settings.py the TEMPLATE_DIRS an extra folder info

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'apps/app1/app1_templ').replace('\\','/'),
```

Rendering the page always seems to give EMPTY no matter what.

**Why the a list seems to be empty?**

Comment: Shouldn't the `apps/app1/app1_templ` be `apps/app1/templates/` ?

Comment: Well the rendering works ok ie it displays the EMPTY string on rendered page. It just don't bring the content of the querySet 'info' returned as 'a'

Comment: And if you put the contents of app1_templ.html right into main.html, it doesn't say EMPTY?

Comment: When I put the content of app1_templ.html directly into the main.html and the views form app1 directory functionality into the views form the main project it works perfectly.
But when I simply copy the code form the views form the main project to the views in the app1 folder and the html form the main.html to app1_template.html it is not working ie. simply the QuerySet represented as 'b' in the template gives the output of {% empty %} tag. (here the 'empty' string)

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the `context_instance`:

```
return render_to_response('main.html', {'a': info}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I have modyfied the views.py form the main project replacing the previous call to render_to_response and importing the 
from django.template import RequestContext but the result is still the same.